# Dynamic horizontal list with variable width lines and content between nodes

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a system that generates a list of nodes which may or may not have additional elements between the nodes. I want to visualize this list horizontally with lines connecting the nodes as shown in the example below.

The content between two nodes is variable and can even contain more complex elements like images and tables. The nodes themselves are labeled with only text (Point A, Point B, etc.).

[image: Fig 1]

### Code & What I have tried so far

In my first attempt at trying to visualize the nodes I simply used a vertical list with the `:before` and `:after` CSS pseudo-elements to draw the lines between the nodes. I am however having difficulty translating this approach to a horizontal list.

**Horizontal approach:** (updated thanks to [Mayank Gupta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021458/2847113) below)

```css
h1, h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
ul li {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 flex: 2;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li:after {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -5px;
 left: 0;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 font-weight: 300;
 content: "\f111";
 height: 17px;
 width: 23px;
 background: #fff;
}
ul h2 {
 margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
 padding: 0;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
 border: none;
}
ul li > div {
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
 <li>
  <h2>Node A</h2>
  <div>Content</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>Node B</h2>
  <div>Content</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>Node C</h2>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**Problems with this method:**

- All nodes are equal width causing the last node to take up space needlessly (last node never has any content to show), in effect this prevents the list from using all available horizontal space (or at least seemingly);
- The line is sensitive to font-size changes causing it to misalign;
- The node labels are centered using a negative offset, this probably isn't the best method;
- The content div is taken out of the document flow in order to center it between the nodes, this potentially allows it to overlap the node labels as is the case in this example

How could I resolve these issues?

### Constraints

- I only support the latest version of modern browsers, so no compatibility is required for ancient browsers;
- I prefer an HTML(5) and CSS only approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer - essentially you add `display:flex` to the `ul` list and make sure that the nodes have fixed size by using `flex:0 0 auto` and a fixed width. This would allow for the context between to be variable in size.

Concerning the connection of the nodes, although it could be done by using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, there's an easier way to do it; just use a pseudo-element for the whole list (the `ul` element) that goes side-by-side along the width of the element (in the example actually `left` and `right` have a value of 30px to compensate the arbitrary side padding I set).

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="node"><label>Point A</label></li>
  <li class="context"><span>Content here Content here Content here</span></li>
  <li class="node"><label>Point B</label></li>
  <li class="context"><span>Content here</span></li>
  <li class="node"><label>Point C</label></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  height: 2px;
  background: steelblue;
}

.node {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid steelblue;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.node label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.context {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.context span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ksxtz60/

Comment: This seems to do what I was after, thanks! The power of flex still quite amazes me.

Comment: @Thomas imagine the possibilities of grid. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
h1, h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul {
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li {
        position: relative;
    width: 33%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
ul li:after {
 position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 300;
    content: "\f111";
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
 <li>
  <h2>Node A</h2>
  <div>Content</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>Node B</h2>
  <div>Content</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>Node C</h2>
  <div>Content</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution! This helped me to get to something close to my goal, however I'm now facing a number of new issues. I have updated my question above, do you have an idea how to resolve those?

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat answers your question[*] [* = however I wrote most of this code before I read on seeing your first image, without seeing the h2/div content].

The bulk of the answer is HTML/CSS, but there is a small bit of javascript to set the li class [of the nodes up to the point selected] to active.

Run the snippet and click on the node items in turn to see the lines being drawn.

**EDIT: Re. your questions:**

With regard to the last node, you could choose to give it a different width, remove border-width/margin/padding or display:none. If you use the [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selector, you can give the last item different property values as required, using CSS.

Regarding different fonts/misalignment, I'd say the same is true of most code using different fonts. Try to stick use one font consistently (I'd regard it as better practice in this instance). As for misalignment, if it's varying image sizes that are mostly causing it to misalign, try using a fixed width with 
`object-fit` (contain/scale-down should display best for you) You can set an overflow to divs, and don't forget `wrap`

Label-centering: have you tried simply adding `text-align: center;` ? Not sure what suggest regarding the negative offset, as this is dependent/relative to other css. Would have to see full css/html layout.

Re. potentially overlapping divs: set a `max-width` for your content and `overflow`/`overflow-y` to auto if necessary.

Hope this helps!

```js
var nodelist1 = document.getElementById("connect");

var mynodes = nodelist1.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < mynodes.length; i++) {
  mynodes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var currNode = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    currNode[0].className = currNode[0].className.replace("active", "");
    this.className += "active";
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  /* padding: 2em;*/
}

#connect {
  font-weight: 300;
  content: "\f111";
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0em .8em;
  line-height: 4em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: navy;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: -3em;
  min-width: 4em;
  /*width of connecting line*/
  height: .2em;
  background: maroon;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
  /*at pos 1, other nodes are 'disabled' line is light blue*/
}

.active {
  background: navy;
}

.active~li {
  background: lightgray;
}

.active~li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 5em;
  max-height: 6em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.active .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="connect">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li>
    <h2>Node A</h2>
    <div class="content">Manuel: hello how are you I speak English I learn it from a book</div>
  </li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution! I've been able to get a bit closer to my goal, but unfortunately not without issues. I have updated my question above with new code and the issues listed below it. Do you perhaps have an idea how I could tackle those?